# I am a bit confused on this java project. The main method shows "inputNums(5)" as a method caller which is the size

Tags: java

> I am confused on how to use a method caller with just a number. In
> this case, in "inputNums(5)," 5 is the size of the array, and I have
> to make another method implementing the given size. Any other mistakes
> found in this project is appreciated. The code has comments on what
> the code does.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Point;

class Main
{
  static Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] nums;
    String lastName;
    char lastInitial;
    Point myPoint = new Point();
  
    System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers:"); 
    nums = inputNums(5); //I am most confused on this part, how do I work with an argument like this one
 
    outputMin(nums);

    changePoint(myPoint, nums);
    System.out.println("The first two numbers are now stored in this object:");
    System.out.println(myPoint);

// DO NOT CHANGE THE ABOVE CODE

    //enter last name then outputs a greeting
    System.out.println("Please enter your last name:");
    lastName = keyIn.next();
    lastInitial = lastName.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Hello Mx. " + lastInitial);
  }

  //makes an array with 5 user inputs of integers
  public static int inputNums (int 5) {
      int[5] = keyIn.nextInt();
  }

  //checks each number and outputs the smallest
  public static int outputMin (int[] nums) {
    var smallest = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = nums[i];
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest value is " + smallest);
  }

  //makes and prints a new point that has the first two points in the array
  public static Point changePoint (Point myPoint, int[] nums) 
  {
    int x = nums[0];
    int y = nums[1];
    myPoint = new Point(x, y);
    System.out.println(myPoint);
  }
}

/* Sample output 
   (PLEASE REPLACE THIS WITH THE OUTPUT THAT YOU GET):

Please enter 5 numbers:
2 4 6 8 10
The smallest value is 2
The first two numbers are now stored in this object:
java.awt.Point[x=2,y=4]
Please enter your last name: Persiko
Hello Mx. P


Please enter 5 numbers:
50            
40
30
20
10
The smallest value is 10
The first two numbers are now stored in this object:
java.awt.Point[x=50,y=40]
Please enter your last name: Smith
Hello Mx. S

*/
```

> error: identifier expected
> public static int inputNums (int 5) <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `nums` you will see that it is an Array

```
int[] nums;
```

so it is necessary for the return value of `inputNums` to define in its signature that it will return an Array

e.g.

```
public static int [] inputNums (int size)
```

now we can use the number passed into the method to create and return an int array

```
public static int [] inputNums (int size) {
      int values [] = new int [size];
      // loop for each element getting the int value
      // put into values [i]
      return values;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, it also turns out I had to use return for each method in my project as well. I now understand that you can calling a method with a number is just filling the method argument with the number so the method can have an output. I also see that I will have to pay more attention to the method datatype since I am outputting an array to use, which is int[].